# Unable to use gigabit ethernet

Tags: networking, router, drivers, ethernet

A couple months back, I lost the wired gigabit ethernet connection to my desktop out of nowhere. Since then I've been limited to 100Mbps Full Duplex.

Could you help me understand how to get the gigabit connection back?

My current setup is as follows:

- **OS**: Windows 10 Home (Version 20H2, OS Build 19042.746)
- **Motherboard**: Asus Prime Z270-A (BIOS Version 1302)
- **Ethernet Adapter**: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (Driver Version 12.17.8.7)
- **Router**: Asus RT-AC1200G+ (Firmware Version 3.0.0.4.382_52272)
- **Ethernet Cabling**: CAT 6

And I already tried the following:

- Tested the wired ethernet connection in 2 other laptops, and both of them were able to use the gigabit connection
- Reinstalled Windows from scratch
- Installed all windows updates
- Updated BIOS to the latest version
- Updated the router firmware to the latest version
- Uninstalled and reinstalled LAN Drivers to the latest version
- Switched between the router ports
- Ran from Linux Mint, but the limitation persisted
- Cleaned desktop's ethernet ports

The BIOS and LAN drivers were downloaded from the Asus website here: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-A/HelpDesk_Download/

Here are the screenshots of me trying to force a gigabit connection, and a 100Mbps connection:
[image]

Comment: You have a cable problem. Fast Ethernet will work with two pairs, but Gigabit Etherenet requires all four pairs.

Comment: @RonMaupin the question already says "Tested the wired ethernet connection in 2 other laptops, and both of them were able to use the gigabit connection"

Comment: @DavidPostill, it is a cable problem. For example, there could be something where one of the pins in the laptop interface got moved, broken or dirty, and the cable cannot make a good connection of all four pairs.

Comment: It might also be noteworthy that Gigabit Ethernet _requires_ you use auto-negotiation. Everything else is non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've done a good job of process-of-elimination troubleshooting for just about everything but the desktop's NIC. Get a $20 USB 3 to gigabit Ethernet adapter and see if your PC can do gigabit Ethernet with a different adapter/NIC.

Gigabit Ethernet uses all 8 conductors in the cable, whereas 100 Mbit only uses 4. So when something works for 100 Mbit but not gigabit, it's almost always in some way a problem with those 4 conductors that are only used by gigabit.

Don't forget that the 8P8C receptacle on the NIC is not the end of the Ethernet signal path. The last few millimeters of your Ethernet connection are circuit board traces on your NIC, between the 8P8C receptacle and the chips that truly receive and decode the signals. Sometimes a marginal solder joint can fail early due the stress of thermal expansion and contraction day after day. Or a card can get damaged, a surface trace can be scratched off, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation  In the meantime, I bought a new PCIe NIC and tested it, and it worked: https://prnt.sc/ymw0a0